# Any recommendation for a former Rails 2.3 users to migrate to Rails 5.x?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I used to program using Rails 2.3.x heavily, but it has been a while since I coded. I took a managerial position of a big company, and I don't have enough time to play with my old code. Recently, I realized that I need to hone my skill and would like to start with my old web services and start from there.

Any recommendation for me how to get started?

Comment: Find and follow the migration guides. Upgrade sequentially (rails 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5, not 2 -> 5).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be aware that this is a multi-step process and can take a long time. Make sure to test for bugs after accomplishing each step since they'll definitely appear.

- The first step is migrating from [Rails 2.3 to Rails 3.0](https://medium.com/airbnb-engineering/upgrading-airbnb-from-rails-2-3-to-rails-3-0-269b5b0f2ad0).
- Second you want to upgrade to [Ruby 1.9.3](https://web.archive.org/web/20150915222435/https://eng.uservoice.com/blog/2012/03/04/how-to-upgrade-a-rails-2.3-app-to-ruby-1.9.3/).
- Pushing from Rails 3.0 to Rails 5.x is covered by RailsGuides which has [excellent documentation](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html). You'll notice there are a number of interim steps:

  1. Rails 3.0 -> Rails 3.1
  2. Rails 3.1 -> Rails 3.2
  3. Rails 3.2 -> Rails 4.0
  4. Rails 4.0 -> Rails 4.1
  5. Rails 4.1 -> Rails 4.2
  6. Rails 4.2 -> Rails 5.0
  7. Rails 5.0 -> Rails 5.1

I would strongly suggest adding unit tests to core features if you don't have them. It helps finding issues significantly easier as you progress.